# Modify XML in foreach loop in PHP

Tags: php, xml, foreach

How to update/modify the XML in foreach loop ?

I have an XML like so:

```
<items>
    <item>
        <client>1</client>
        <retailer>RET1</retailer>
        <code>c553d8be7f3e88bda6a26b8e7eacd11a6001e0ba5f3c6e26ddbf4a08d9e277f3</code>
        <id>1234567891011</id>
    </item>
    <item>
        <client>1</client>
        <retailer>RET1</retailer>
        <code>9afb1b44a582d76159626d05aaf414983625530d83cbfa40a1359bf0afd9225b</code>
        <id>1234567891011</id>
    </item>
    <item>
        <client>1</client>
        <retailer>RET1</retailer>
        <code>90f5ff04e07b0701b6db3c6e44ed2f1636b64fb9eb78f9121dc684b8b8339741</code>
        <id>1234567891011</id>
    </item>
</items>
```

In my code I have a foreach loop:

```
foreach( $xml as $code )
{
    // Remove each item, so to keep the only one inside, and each time move forward by removing all other items

    // if ($xml->node->code != $code ) 
        // remove it

}
```

I don't know how do I remove each time not equal node to the code value, any suggestion ?

Comment: Better create a new xml with the matched one rather than removing unmatched

Comment: any tips how to do it with `DOMDOcument` ? thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like below:

```
<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_string($string);//$string contains your xml
$item = $xml->item;
$count_node = count($item);
for($i=0;$i<$count_node;$i++)
{
    echo $item[$i]->code;// access the tags like this and check your conditions
}
?>
```

Let me know if you persist any issue

Answer (score 0):

try with domdocument and removechild to remove the nodes.

```
$client = $items->getElementsByTagName('client')->item(0);
$items->removeChild($client);
```

Comment: you are doing in the first line `$client = $items->` ... how do I load DOMDocument into the `$items` ? `$items = DOMDocument::loadXML($xml_string)` is not working